# com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, apk, ubuntu-14.04

I am using React Native 0.26 and trying to play around with Google Plus Sign in from the below npm for Android application.

```
npm install react-native-google-signin --save
```

I am using command-line(react-native run-android) to build debug apks directly on my devices.

Followed all the installation steps very carefully. By default, my builds are working only on Build tools version 1.2.3 on build.gradle(/android/) and it used to work for other projects but I am having the below error in this project because I had to include the below line in build.gradle file,

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'` // <--- add this

and when I add this, I also have to modify the `distributionUrl` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip` on `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

After doing all the modifications when I tried to run the build command, it never installs the updated apk on the device and it is stuck at 99% progress.

**Below is the detailed error**,

```
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Micromax Q372 - 5.0' for app:debug
08:26:35 E/1526411097: Error while uploading app-debug.apk : Unknown failure ([CDS]close[0])
Unable to install /home/sid/react/gplus/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all 
at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:91)

......

:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue trying to install an APK on a specific device.

To solve I listed all the connected devices with `adb devices` and I identified the right one, then I ran `run-android` specifying the device ID:

```
react-native run-android --deviceId MY-DEVICE-ID
```